# Finding specific entry in the table causes Column not found exception

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite

I have written database app in which I am trying to find a specific entry in the database. I get an exception that the specific column in which I am trying to find entry doesn't exit, although inserting new data in the datebase doesn't cause any exception. Here is the code:

```
public void findEmail(String findEm) {

    Cursor c = sqlDB.query(DB_TABLE_NAME, dbCols, DB_EMAIL_COL + "=" + findEm, null, null, null, null);

    if(c!=null)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();

        String found = c.getString(1); // id = col 0, email = col 1

        Toast.makeText(context, "Email FOund "+ found, 0).show();
    }
}
```

I get exception that the Email column doesn't exist. Is there anything wrong with the syntax or am I missing something in the code.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure especially as I'm no Java developer, but shouldn't it be :

```
Cursor c = sqlDB.query(DB_TABLE_NAME, dbCols, DB_EMAIL_COL + "='" + findEm + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks I am learning sqlite stuff now. I never used it before. :P

Answer (score 0):

Your code comment says:

```
id = col 0, email = col 1
            ^^^^^
```

and your error message says:

```
Email column doesn't exist
^^^^^
```

so I assume your `DB_EMAIL_COL` has the value `Email`, but it should have the value `email`.

Remember, `Email != email`